# Cancel or Save changes made to a custom object in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that has an ItemsSource set to a ObservableCollection of custom objects, that is passed from a window to the usercontrol that contains the DataGrid, and while this works quite well and changes are registered in both directions I would like to have the ability to cancel any changes made in my UserControl if i click a cancel button.

Is there some way to defer any changes I make in my DataGrid to my ItemSource in my parent window? or conversely some way to cancel changes if I so choose. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is my current code;

```
   public UserControl1(ObservableCollection<ContourControl.RectangleContour> list1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));

        itemCollectionViewSource.Source = list1;

        //here i create some columns and bind the data

        DataGridViewer.ItemsSource = list1;
        DataGridViewer.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    }

    private void Cancel(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if i click this i would like any changes to list1 to be reverted or ignored

        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow((DependencyObject)sender);
        if (parentWindow != null)
        {
            parentWindow.Close();
        }
    }

    private void OK(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if i click this i would like the changes to carry on to my list, as it currently does instantly

        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow((DependencyObject)sender);
        if (parentWindow != null)
        {
            parentWindow.Close();
        }
    }
```

and here is the code that launches my usercontrol and passes the original list i have the data stored in.

```
                Window window = new Window
            {
                Height = 200,
                Width = 765,
                Content = new UserControl1(list1: rectContourList),
            };
            window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You're basically asking how to implement undo functionality. This question already deals with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984674/datagrid-and-mvvm-with-undo-redo

Answer (score 0):

You can set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`to your textbox.

```
 <TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding tbval, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

Then on "ok" button click update the source

```
 private void OK_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindingExpression binding = tb1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();
        }
```

And on "cancel" just set the previous property back if you want to show the previous value on the textbox, else you can just leave it empty.

```
private void Cancel_Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //tbval is the property binded to Textbox
            tbval = tbval;
        }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx